# How to create Dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Somebody know if it is possible to how to create Dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory from powershell instead of passing from “Rule builder in the Azure portal” ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory from powershell**

As I tried below script to create dynamic membership rules for groups in Azure Active Directory from powershell

You can get the Administrative units Object ID like below

**AzurePortal>Administrative units>Select your Administrative Unit>Properties (Preview)**

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/P7bTMmt.png)]

You can get the Group Object ID like below

**AzurePortal>Azure Active Directory>Groups>Select your Group>**

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/vfg9G1U.png)]

```
#Install Azure AD Module
 
Install-Module -Name AzureADPreview

#Connect to Azure Account

Connect-AzureAD

#Get AzureADMSAdministrativeUnit Details

Get-AzureADMSAdministrativeUnit -id <AzureADMSAdministrativeUniObjectID>

#Create Dynamic membership rules to Exiting AzureADMSAdministrativeUnit

Set-AzureADMSAdministrativeUnit -Id <AzureADMSAdministrativeUnit ObjectID> -MembershipRule '(user.Department -eq "HR") -or (user.usageLocation -eq "India")'

#Get Azure AD Group details

Get-AzureADMSGroup -id <AzureADMSGroupobjectID>

#Create Dynamic membership rules to AzureAD group

Set-AzureADMSGroup -id <AzureADMSGroupobjectID> -MembershipRule '(user.Department -eq "IT") -or (user.usageLocation -eq "Canada")'

#Create New group with Dynamic Membership rule

New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName "Dynamic Group 01" -Description "Dynamic group created from PS" -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -GroupTypes "DynamicMembership" -MembershipRule "(user.department -contains ""Marketing"")" -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
```

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/P757RtM.png)]

Finally Created Group with Dynamic Membership Rule

[image: (https://i.imgur.com/C8GHyNS.png)]